# Using pytorch_lightning.loggers.MLFlowLogger with azure machine learning studio raises exception mlflow.exceptions.RestException: BAD_REQUEST

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service, mlflow, pytorch-lightning

I'm trying to locally train pytorch_lightning model and log metrics using  pytorch_lightning.loggers.MLFlowLogger.

It was working fine until last weekend. Now training crashes with error:

```
mlflow.exceptions.RestException: BAD_REQUEST: Response: {'Error': {'Code': 'UserError', 'Severity': None, 'Message': 'Metric once published using sync API should always use sync API to publish following metrics', 'MessageFormat': None, 'MessageParameters': None, 'ReferenceCode': None, 'DetailsUri': None, 'Target': None, 'Details': [], 'InnerError': None, 'DebugInfo': None, 'AdditionalInfo': None}, 'Correlation': {'operation': '', 'request': ''}, 'Environment': 'northeurope', 'Location': 'northeurope', 'Time': '2021-07-27T14:06:23.7035319+00:00', 'ComponentName': 'run-history', 'error_code': 'BAD_REQUEST'}
```

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It was a bug in azure machine learning studio. Now it should be fixed.

Solution is to change versions of azure-mlflow and azure-core packages on training machine.

Currently (28.07.2021) logging metrics works with versions:

```
azureml-core==1.30.0
azureml-mlflow==1.30.0
```

Currently (02.08.2021) logging metrics works with versions:

```
azureml-core==1.18.0.post4
azureml-mlflow==1.18.0
```